# How do I create a view that groups by a person when the task has multiple people assigned?

Tags: 2013, task-list, multiple-values, ms-project, task-assignment

I have a task list linked to MS project which links fine. However my SP13 list has two columns for different resource/people.

Both people are working on the same particular project, but may be working on several different projects independently.

The link to MS Project only picks up the first resource column. If I add the second resource to the same column I lose the ability to have a view in my SP13 list that groups projects by each person. How do I get a round this?

Thanks in advance.